# No Foundation.URL struct exposed to Xamarin?

Tags: xamarin, foundation

In Xamarin, I have access to `Foundation.NSUrl`. This is fine, but I have a native (Swift) library that I am binding to, that exposes a property of struct type `Foundation.URL?`.

I can't see this type defined in Xamarin and an attempt to use `NSUrl` instead generates a build error. Does the `URL` type exist somewhere in Xamarin or is there an equivalent type I can use in a binding, or is there a definition I can use in StructsAndEnums.cs?

Comment: Binding to Swift libraries is not yet supported. URL is an iOS SDK type that is only defined in Swift. At this time, to bind to swift libraries, you would want to wrap the swift API in Objective-C and bind to the Obj-C. Here's a good article on binding to Swift libraries: https://medium.com/@Flash3001/binding-swift-libraries-xamarin-ios-ff32adbc7c76

Comment: Thanks, I'm binding to the Swift library without too much difficulty. Just the URL structure I'm having trouble with currently. As it's a structure maybe there's a way of defining an equivalent in the binding code, in StructsAndEnums.cs for example.

Comment: @fractor,About binding swift in xamarin, I just find one sample:https://github.com/Flash3001/Xamarin.BindingSwiftLibrarySample/tree/master/XamarinBinding, and one article about binding swift:https://medium.com/liferay-mobile/binding-java-and-swift-libraries-for-xamarin-projects-5df4a71f1f10